# What is wrong with my question? ( about whether I can implement EF5 TPT to run on Windows XP )

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question

I am wondering how I could have framed [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963417/can-i-implement-entity-framework-5-tpt-on-windows-xp) better, or whether I have asked it in the wrong place, and if so where should I have asked it.

On a forum, I might have asked ... anyone using EF5 TPT on Windows XP if so how do you get it to work?

Comment: I take it the answer that was posted didn't help?

Comment: @KateGregory: Mash all that into an answer so I can upvote it.  Include something about unreasonable expectations of hand-holding. :)

Comment: It has been flagged as duplicate, but I disagree that it is duplicate, since my question is about working on XP, and hence not Framework 4.5

Comment: @RobertHarvey your wish is my command

Comment: I think the correct answer has been posted now. It will take a while for me to test it.

Comment: All (or at least most) of the additional information that was posted in a series of edits should have been there from the beginning. I'll publically admit to having downvoted [the original version of your question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17963417/1) when I saw it soon after posting, because it didn't contain nearly enough information to be answerable. I've since retracted that downvote because I believe it no longer applies. So you're going in the right direction!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My first piece of advice is to get rid of all the [Update] business. Write a coherent question that makes sense to someone reading the whole thing for the first time. Put the actual question at the top.

I went to your question to edit it a little - some `backticking` around inline code, a blank line before a code block so that it would format properly - but I didn't get far. I did find a line that said vaguely "I get error messages" and later an [update] that said what they were, so I brought the error messages up to where you said you get them and deleted the [update]. But then I ran into trouble.

**When you solve one problem but then something else happens, don't keep adding more and more story into your question.** Leave the first one alone - for example, it was a duplicate of something, fine, let it be closed as that - and ask a fresh one. When you get that solved, accept the answer for that one and if you now have a third problem, ask that as a separate question. Updating the question as drastically as you are invalidates old answers and frustrates people.

We've talked about this on Meta before: take a look at 
[Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) and [Guidance To Avoid Chameleon Behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169052/guidance-to-avoid-chameleon-behavior) and see if you recognize your behavior. It's a great sign that you have come here and asked for advice. This particular aspect of SO culture is a little unusual.

Comment: +1 for a lot of reasons, but especially, "It's a great sign that you have come here and asked for advice."